# How Can I Make the Score Go Up One Point When a Button is Clicked on XCode using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Sorry for the easy question I am very new to IOS developing. What I would like to do is make the UILabel which is set to 0 go up by 1 every time a button is tapped on. Here is the default code given On the ViewController.swift and I have created an Outlet for the Label and Action for the Button.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var score: UILabel!

@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CHANGE LABEL NAME TO BE MORE DESCRIPTIVE
CREATE SCORE VARIABLE AND START IT AT 0 SO YOU HAVE A SCORE TO PRESENT FROM THE START
MAKE IT BEAUTIFUL



import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!
private var score = 0

@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
    score += 1
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.pinkColor()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to count. something like `var counter = 0` and in func button you put `counter +=1` and `score.text = "\(counter)"`. I didnt try that right now on Xcode, but as far as I know that should work

Comment: Just tried it, works :) You can also put `score.text = "\(counter)"` into viewDidLoad to show 0 in the beginning... If my answer helped you, please mark it as right answer :)

Answer (score -1):

This can be one way of doing it:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func updateScore(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Check if String can be parsed to integer
    if let score = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(scoreLabel.text!) {
        var myInt = score.integerValue
        myInt = myInt + 1
        scoreLabel.text = "\(myInt)"
    } else {
        scoreLabel.text = "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer was accepted sometime back. Then it got -1. Can you please explain reason for changing to -1.

Comment: Score shouldn't be contained to the scope of the button call

Comment: Problem statement is "What I would like to do is make the UILabel which is set to 0 go up by 1 every time a button is tapped on" . Hence the above code achieves that purpose by incrementing ui label text by 1 on every button tap. Score is local variable used to capture existing value of label. It's just another way of achieving result and I tested this code in program before putting it here.